# Get data from DynamoDB based on numerical order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way data from DynamoDB can be sorted based on sort order and name.

For instance, I have few records with the below data:

1. order: 1, name: aaa
2. order: 2, name bbb
3. order: 3, name: ccc
4. order: 25, name aaa

when I am getting response from dynamodb, I am getting in order 1,2,4,3. My expected order is 1,2,3 and then 4.

This is the query I am using:

```py
results = table.query(
    IndexName="table-Id-index",
    KeyConditionExpression=Key("id").eq('2'),
    ScanIndexForward=True
)
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB uses byte-order for sorting, that means it will look at each character in order and sort them based on that.

The numbers are: 1,2,3,25

The ways DynamoDB interprets this for sorting is actually like this:

- [1, NULL]
- [2, NULL]
- [3, NULL]
- [2, 5]

It first checks out all the first characters and sorts based on that and then the next character.

- [1, NULL]
- [2, NULL]
- [2, 5]
- [3, NULL]

Since 2 < 3, your 25 or 2-and-5 as DynamoDB sees it get's sorted before the three. NULL < 5, so it gets sorted after the 2.

If you want to do a more numerical sort, I suggest you store your numbers as strings with leading zeroes, that will work:

- 00001
- 00002
- 00003
- 00025

Answer (score 0):

You sort key type is a String, so DynamoDB sorts items in lexicographical order.
In lexicographical order 25 comes before 3.

From [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.String):

> DynamoDB collates and compares strings using the bytes of the
> underlying UTF-8 string encoding. For example, "a" (0x61) is greater
> than "A" (0x41), and "¿" (0xC2BF) is greater than "z" (0x7A).
>
> You can use the string data type to represent a date or a timestamp.
> One way to do this is by using ISO 8601 strings, as shown in these
> examples:
>
> 2016-02-15 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z 20150311T122706Z

If you want to sort items in Numerical Order, you must change the sort key type to [Number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Number).